# Download logs using pymavlink

Tags: dronekit-python, dronekit, mavlink

```
from pymavlink import mavutil

# Create a MAVLink connection
master = mavutil.mavlink_connection('tcp:147.182.195.25:30593')

# Send LOG_REQUEST_LIST message
start_index = 0  
end_index = 0xFFFF  
master.mav.log_request_list_send(
    target_system=1,   
    target_component=0,
    start=0,         
    end=0xffff            
)
# # m
while True:
    msg = master.recv_match(type='LOG_ENTRY', blocking=True)
    if msg is None:
        break
    print("Log file: %s" % msg)

# Close the connection
master.close()
print("Size of received log data:", log_data_size)
```

im able to get log entry how to downlod those logs
i have tried log_request_data
and nothing is happening